# Can I inject process parameters when the process is in running state?

Tags: jbpm

Question may be very silly,but I have requirement as such.
If the above asked question is not possible,then need to change the approach.
Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: "inject process parameters" means.. add process parameters or change variable values on a process instance?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible, but IMO it will be a better approach to have placeholders to the things that you expect to have in a process. If you can elaborate a little bit more on the use case we can give you a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new variable to your process instance using the setVariable method. Before, you have to cast your process instance to WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl class.

```
org.kie.api.runtime.process.ProcessInstance processInstance = ...
WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl processInstanceImpl = (WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl) processInstance;
processInstanceImpl.setVariable("newVar", "newVal");
```